# 'index was outside the bounds of the array' exception handling error

Tags: c#, exception

I am using the below code to find the base address of a running process. It's within a timer control for other purposes. If the target process is not running I want to display "Process is not running" in the label text, but keep checking for the running process and when/if found continue with the next code block. I have tried a few ways I thought would work, such as a 'try' with exception handling, but the form I am using to hold the label just freezes, I am quit new to c#. Here is the code,

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region BaseAddress
        Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("process");
        int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
        #endregion
        //Other code
     }
```

The exception when run is: "IndexOutOfRange exception was unhandled"  - Index was outside the bounds of the array. Hopefully someone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a try–catch block to handle the error, you should check whether the process was found *before* trying to access it:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region BaseAddress
    Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("process");
    if (test.Any())
    {
        // Process is running.
        int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
        // Perform any processing you require on the "Base" address here.
    }
    else
    {
         // Process is not running.
         // Display "Process is not running" in the label text.
    }
    #endregion
    //Other code
 }
```

Comment: There seems to be a real trend to use Linq anywhere it *can* be applied.  I'm personally not a fan of that.  An array has a property, Length, designed to reveal it's length directly.  Why wrap that with a Linq extension method?

Comment: Because the name of the LINQ method is more intention-revealing. Translate `test.Any()` to English: “Does the list contain *any* elements?” Translate `test.Length > 0` to English: “Does the list contain more than zero elements?” Which would you prefer?

Comment: If I wanted to do this outside of timer1_Tick, what is the best way to do it? I have tried holding the code in a public class but it doesn't work for some reason. At the moment I am getting the error: the name Base does not eist in the current context throughout other codeblocks within the timer control

Comment: "Does the array have any Length" is just as intention revealing, without adding an unnecessary function call.

Comment: @EricJ.: I disagree, but this is a matter of personal preference. The performance hit will be negligible considering that `GetProcessesByName` is more expensive by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Using Linq adds performance overhead.  Granted it will not matter in this instance, but teaching people to use Linq without thinking about what they are trying to accomplish is not a good thing.

Comment: Instead of Any() how about Some() or AFew() or MoreThanZero().  What a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: Including the if statement causes other code in the timer control  to throw an error: the name Base does not exist in the current context.  But if I remove the if statement, its fine, why?

Comment: @user1166981: Because you’re trying to access the variable from outside its declaration’s scope. Move any code that accesses `Base` *within* the if statement block.

Comment: ok, it is fine if I a) have the process running already, b) don't have the process running, but c) if I have my program running THEN open the target process I get this error: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1166981: I would suggest opening a new question for that error.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region BaseAddress
        Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("process");
        if (test.Length > 0)
        {
            int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
        }
        else
        {
            myLabel.Text = "Process is not running";
        }
        #endregion
        //Other code
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Process with the name "process" does not exist. You need to give a real processname. So the array does not contain any elements. Try debugging to see if the array contains any elements and add error handling or a verification that the array length is higher than 0 before doing the second line of your code.